# R Regular expression

Tags: r

I'm learning about the sub & gsub function, 
and after reading the definition, I still dont understand what is:

".*" , "\s"

specifically, the question ask what does the following code chunk return and I have no clue how it works

`awards <- c("Won 1 Oscar.",
  "Won 1 Oscar. Another 9 wins & 24 nominations.",
  "1 win and 2 nominations.",
  "2 wins & 3 nominations.",
  "Nominated for 2 Golden Globes. 1 more win & 2 nominations.",
  "4 wins & 1 nomination.")`

`sub(".*\\s([0-9]+)\\snomination.*$", "\\1", awards)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

".*" = . means any character and * is 0 or more of the previous.
"\s" = means any white space

So

```
sub(".*           #match any character 0 or more times
\\s               # follow by a space (whitespace)
([0-9]+)          # with at least 1 number the () means extract
\\s               # follow by another space
nomination        # follow by the word "nomination"
.*$",             # with 0 or more characters from end of the line
 "\\1", awards)   # //1 means replace with the first match
```

Given your sample of strings, the first string does not have the word nomination in it so the original string is returned.  The other strings will all match so the number immediately preceding the word "nomination" will be retuned.

Hope this helps.

Comment: so if i type `sub(".*\\s([0-9]+)\\snomination$", "\\1", awards)` (without the ".*" at the end)will it get the same result?, also does the string `([0-9]+)`only have 1 match of the number in this situation?

Comment: Only if there are no characters after the word "nomination"